# Tags meta box don't show when creating a new post type

Tags: metabox, tags

After creating new custom post type with `register_post_type()` function, I don't see the Tags meta box when adding a page of new post type.

It seems that tags metabox should be added manually.
If so, how can I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to do this.

The first is to supply the `taxonomies` keyword in the `register_post_type` arguments array, like so:

```
register_post_type('my_type', array(
    ...
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    ...
));
```

The other is to register your post type and set up its taxonomies at a later point:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'my_type' );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'my_type' );
```

**UPDATE**: Likely you will want some of these taxonomies to be exclusive to your post type. First, taxonomies exists across all post types, that's their strength. If however, you want to be able to add tags that are exclusive to your custom post type you will have to register a custom taxonomy as well.

```
register_taxonomy('my_tax', 'my_type'); // You will have to run this one time for each post type you wish to use
```

The above should do fine, but check out the [`register_taxonomy` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) as there are quite a few arguments you can supply to affect its behavior.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. tnx

Comment: i found that adding `post_tag` for new custom post type also shows the tags used in post type. how can i make it separated ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but if I understand correctly you don't want the default `post_tag` taxonomy terms (which also is available for posts, that is the `post` post type) to be used by *both* the default posts and your custom post type. I have updated my answer with a not about custom taxonomies.